# Permission denied of sysfs attribute file

Tags: permissions, sysfs

As part of firewall implementation I am implementing a sysfs device, which attributes are defined by:

```c
#define FILE_PERMISSIONS S_IWUSR | S_IRUGO
static DEVICE_ATTR(sysfs_att, FILE_PERMISSIONS, display, modify);
```

I have no problem reading from the file using

```bash
cat /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
```

But, as I support modify (store) operation, i plan to interact with the device with commands such as

```bash
echo "0" > /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
```

How ever, this results with

```
-bash: /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att: Permission denied
```

This happens even when I'm using `tee` with sudo.
I also verified that the sys file has the right permission, and it does have write access for user.

Except for what I already tried I can't find a new way to deal with this issue, have any of you any idea?

Edit:
Following your request, A log:

```
fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-118-generic/build M=/home/fw/HW2 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-118-generic'
  LD [M]  /home/fw/HW2/hw2secws.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  LD [M]  /home/fw/HW2/hw2secws.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-118-generic'
fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ sudo insmod hw2secws.ko

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ cat /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
358310

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
0
tee: /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att: Operation not permitted

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ echo "0" > /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
-bash: /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att: Permission denied

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ ls -l /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 נוב  8 21:25 /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ sudo chown fw /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ ls -l /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
-rw-r--r-- 1 fw root 4096 נוב  8 21:25 /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ echo "0" | sudo tee /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
0
tee: /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att: Operation not permitted

fw@fw-VirtualBox:~/HW2$ echo "0" > /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

And an MRE:

```c
static int major_number;
static struct class* sysfs_class = NULL;
static struct device* sysfs_device = NULL;
static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE
}

ssize_t display(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf){
...
}
ssize_t modify(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buff, size_t data_size)
{
...
}

#define FILE_PERMISSIONS S_IWUSR | S_IRUGO
static DEVICE_ATTR(sysfs_att, FILE_PERMISSIONS, display, modify);

int init_sysfs_module(void){
    
    /* Register Char-Device */
    major_number = register_chrdev(0, CHRDEV_NAME, &fops);\
    if (major_number < 0)
        return -1;
        
    /* Create Sysfs-Class */
    sysfs_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(sysfs_class))
    {
        unregister_chrdev(major_number, CHRDEV_NAME);
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Link DEVICE_NAME to sysfs_class */
    sysfs_device = device_create(sysfs_class, NULL, MKDEV(major_number, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME); 
    if (IS_ERR(sysfs_device))
    {
        class_destroy(sysfs_class);
        unregister_chrdev(major_number, CHRDEV_NAME);
        return -1;
    }
    
    /* Modify the device to use defined show/store methods */
    if (device_create_file(sysfs_device, (const struct device_attribute *)&dev_attr_sysfs_att.attr))
    {
        device_destroy(sysfs_class, MKDEV(major_number, 0));
        class_destroy(sysfs_class);
        unregister_chrdev(major_number, CHRDEV_NAME);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void deinit_sysfs_module(void){
    device_remove_file(sysfs_device, (const struct device_attribute *)&dev_attr_sysfs_att.attr);
    device_destroy(sysfs_class, MKDEV(major_number, 0));
    class_destroy(sysfs_class);
    unregister_chrdev(major_number, CHRDEV_NAME);
}

static int __init module_init_function(void) {
    init_sysfs_module();
    HANDLE_NF_HOOKS(REGISTER_NF_HOOKS);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit module_exit_function(void) {
    deinit_sysfs_module();
    HANDLE_NF_HOOKS(CLEAR_NF_HOOKS);
}

module_init(module_init_function);
module_exit(module_exit_function);
```

EDIT2: I also tried:

```
fw@fw-VirtualVox:~/HW2$ sudo su -
root@fw-VirtualBox:~# echo "0" > /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att
-sw: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: "It does have write access for user" ? You mean that user is the file owner ?

Comment: it's the root who is the owner, as `insmod` runs under root hat. you confused me because by this insight i not sure anymore that writing should work without sudo (and i know it is)

Comment: AFAIK S_IWUSR only concerns owner.

Comment: interesting, but i tried `chown & chgrp` to the user, but then i got `echo: write error: Operation not permitted`. This means I made some progress. but still weird because user has write access, so why is it not permitted?

Comment: just adding, that soon im getting afk for few hours, but i will really appreciate if we can keep the conversation later

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Show the result of `ls -l /sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att` and `id` as the user which tries to access the file. Always show the complete commands you use. Please don't use comments to add information; [edit] your question instead.

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you're running under you own user, and what you're running as `root`. The owner of `/sys/class/secws_class/secws_class_secws_device/sysfs_att` is `root`, and `S_IWUSR` means that only the owner (which is `root`) can write to the file. I'm also not sure how exactly you ran `chown` and  `chgrp`. Please follow @Bodo's request and edit your question.

Comment: I noticed that this site does not support `[mre]`. On stackoverflow.com it would be replaced with a link named "minimal reproducible example" referring to an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hi @Bodo and aviro I have done that, hope it is both enough and not too much

Comment: You see different errors: You get `Permission denied` when you try to write to the device file as a user does not have write permission according to the file system or `Operation not permitted` if the file system grants permission. Your code is incomplete. What does the function `modify` return?

Comment: yes, i know that. i din't put the modify code in the example because the bug happens before reaching that point but i will upload if you think its necessary. any how i would love to solve that

Comment: Ok, I have verified my modify method, and indeed after fixing the number of bytes I returned I got rid of the 'Operation not permitted' error. thank you @Bodo. Just to mention that now im operating under roots hat (by sudo su) so my first assumption about staying under user hat was wrong too.

Comment: `modify` can report errors via its return value. When you change the owner to `fw`, the user `fw` might be able to write to the file because in this situation you got the same error message as `root` when your `modify` function probably returned an error indication. To solve the permissions, I suggest to change the group of the sysfs file to a special group, make it writable for the group and assign this group as a supplementary group to all users that are suposed to write to this file. Working in `su` is dangerous. Better use individual `sudo` for commands that need really `root` permissions.

Comment: ok, I will report my results soon. btw, if you like you can post your comments as an answer so i would accept that as a solution